# Distinguish word count by document number in mapper - Hadoop?

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a mapper function on R (using Rhipe for map-reduce). The mapper function is supposed to read the text file and create Corpus. Now, R already has a package called `tm` which does the Text Mining and create DocumentMatrix. If you want to know more about `tm', have a look [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf).

But the problem with using this package in map-reduce is that the matrix is converted to list, and is difficult to create a matrix in Reduce from this jumbled up "list". I found an algorithm for creating corpus using map-reduce in  [this website](http://marcellodesales.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/tf-idf-in-hadoop-part-3-documents-in-corpus-and-tfidf-computation/) , but I'm slightly confused as to how I could find the name or some unique identification of the mapper document.

For the document that I have which is 196MB text file, hadoop spawned 4 mappers (blocksize=64MB). How can I classify the key value pair such that the mapper sends the pair as `((words@document),1)`. The article explains it beautifully. However, I'm having a little trouble understanding how mapper can distinguish the document number it's reading between multiple mappers. As far as I understand, the mapper counter is specific only for the corresponding mapper. Anyone care to elaborate, or provide some suggestions as to what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came up with my own solution. What I did is instead of looking for mapper counts and what not, I added a text at the end of each line followed by number as in "This is a text, n:1". I used `gsub` to create increment. In the mapper, while I read the line, I also read the value n:1. Since the `n` increases for each line, no matter which mapper is reading which line, it gets the correct value of n. I'm then using the value of `n` to create a new key for each line (document) as in ((word@doc=n),1) where `n` is the value of each line number.